# Show friends of friends who have the app facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have an app, and I'd like to display a list of friends of friends who have the app. For example, if you have 10 facebook friends who have the app, and they have 100 friends each, I'd like to be able to display a list of 1000 people.

How can I do this? Where can I find this in the api docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t get friends of friends, there is no way. You can´t even get the list of direct friends anymore, only those who authorized your App too.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog